# dhclient.conf supersede stanzas ignored

Tags: networking, dhcp, resolv.conf, dhclient, resolvconf

I'm putting the following lines at the top (also tried the bottom) of my `dhclient.conf` file:

```
send host-name "hostname";
supersede domain-name "my-domain-name"
supersede domain-search "my-domain-name"
supersede search "my-domain-name"
```

Nevertheless, my `/etc/resolv.conf` file is as follows:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 123.123.123.123
nameserver 123.123.123.123
search dhcp-supplied-domain-name
```

I've changed the domain names and IP addresses to protect my systems.

How can I get this change to be reflected in my `resolv.conf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you quote it, your `dhclient.conf` lacks a terminating semicolon after each `supersede` statement.

Comment: Nah, just an oversight. Glad the solution was found.